# Do I need to create a separate button method for sensors?

Tags: android, android-button, android-sensors

I have currently created an accelerometer for my application, I wanted to create two buttons where I can start and stop the accelerometer to gather data. At the moment the accelerometer constantly runs. I wanted to know do I have to create a separate onclick method for these buttons? as what I have now doesn't work on my phone/eclipse. Any help will be appreciated.My button code is in the onResume() method and the onPause() method, is that correct?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class movement extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
    Button startButton, stopButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movement);
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              mSensorManager.registerListener(movement.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            }
        });


    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               mSensorManager.unregisterListener(movement.this);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
        TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
        TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText("0.0");
            tvY.setText("0.0");
            tvZ.setText("0.0");
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
            tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
            tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (deltaX > deltaY) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.horizontal);
            } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertical);
            } else {
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not quite correct. You should add the Clicklisteners in the onCreate() method of 
your activity because the onResume() is only called when the activity is brought to the front again and the onPause() is only called when it moves to the background.

See this part of the documentation from google for more information on the activity lifecycle: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Here is the picture I am refering to:
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Also, you can use the onClick tag in your layout XML file to add the method call to the button. You usually don't have to implement your own listens on the predefined buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need an action to stop the sensor, so `stopButton` need his own listener, and is very easy

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              mSensorManager.registerListener(movement.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

            }
        });
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              // your code
            }
        });
```

Respect that create the listeners in `onResume`, is better create in `onCreate`, because the  listeners are going to be created only one time in the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), besides that if you create in `onResume`, they would be create more that one time. Imagine that you create the activity (`onResume` is called), navigate to another activity, and return to the activity (`onResume` is called again)